# text size of imported SVG in LYX output too big

Tags: lyx, svg

I have inserted an svg image into lyx 2.2.0, that I run on windows.

I made this image with ORIGIN and imported it as PDF in INKSCAPE, where I added some text.

In LYX the image looks nice, but when I view the PDF the text originating from ORIGIN is way too big.

Does someone know how to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried scaling the image down in the settings in LyX?